# PHP 5.4 old auth on shared server, fixing without editing the mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, shared-hosting

I just upgraded my developement box's PHP to the latest version, `5.4.5`. This developement machine connects to a remote **MySQL server**, residing on a **shared server** that I lease from a hosting company.

Trying to connect to my remote MySQL server using simple `mysql_connect('myserver.com', 'user', 'password')` results in the following error:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file in file.php on line 2

Simply, as advised, just executing:

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('my-password');
```

wouldn't change anything. 
The same applies when executing

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE;
```

After a bit of searching, I realized that **I needed quite deep access to the MySQL server to be able to fix this problem**, which I do not have. Trying to execute this query:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('my-password')
  WHERE User='my_user' AND Host='my-server';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Simply gives me the following error:

> 1142 - UPDATE command denied to user 'u0112918'@'www10.aname.net' for table 'user'

Requests to have the company execute the query for me has, so far, been unsuccessfull. So my question is if there's any way to **fix this on the client side, without involving the MySQL server?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, try executing the following query through a **tool other then PhpMyAdmin**, such as Mysql Workbench or through a shell:

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0; 
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('passwordString');
```

You should be allowed to change your own password without DML Rights on user-table.

Edit: since it did not resolve the issue - when "read_only" is enabled for the database then you need super rights to change (even your own) password ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html )

Comment: Executed that query, it, however, still gives me the same error.. Super wierd.

Comment: sorry to hear, you can't use any update/insert into the database with that user? Taken from mysql manual:   The SET PASSWORD statement assigns a password to an existing MySQL user account. When the read_only system variable is enabled, the SUPER privilege is required to use SET PASSWORD, in addition to whatever other privileges might be required.

Comment: Executing the command through MySQL workbench did the trick, have no idea why that is. I'll edit your answer a bit and mark it as answered. Thanks a ton for your help!